# How to make a shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a function in functions.php how can i make that function as short code?

```
function the_top_qa_users(){
  global $wpdb;
      echo "<h3>Popular Users</h3>";

  $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='_qa_rep' AND meta_value > 0  ORDER BY CONVERT(meta_value, SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0 , 5");

      foreach ( $results as $result ) {    
        the_qa_user_link( $result->user_id );           
        echo get_avatar($result->user_id);    
      }
}
```

and in my page.php i called like `<?php if(is_page('Home')) { the_top_qa_users();} ?>` how can i make a short code for this?

Comment: [This](http://www.bluesignaldesign.co.uk/blog/create-shortcode-wordpress/) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function the_top_qa_users(){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'the_top_qa_users' );
```

Access it  Just type `[foobar]` into your editor and WordPress will dynamically replace the text as needed.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add the `if(is_page('Home')) { the_top_qa_users();` block inside the function.

Comment: Depends upon conditions/Requirements.

Comment: @AmalMurali will it may slow the site?

Comment: @Naveen it depends upon your query time. And how many time you will call it on page.

Comment: i have now in amals way, but someone told me it will slow the site I have only calling this function in my home page, user images and links will change accordingly. will it slow the site?

Comment: then add the shortcode under the home page check condition just like Amal mentioned.like `if(is_home()){ shortcode}`

Comment: @MahmoodRehman how can i return these too items the_qa_user_link( $result->user_id );           
echo get_avatar($result->user_id);